# creating a module that contains a store_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, module

```
module ServiceBackupable::AWS
  store_accessor :data, :last_backup_at
  def backup
    ...
  end
end
```

$ServiceBackupable::AWS

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `store_accessor' for ServiceBackupable::AWS:Module
```

to resolve this have included ActiveRecord::Store

```
module ServiceBackupable::AWS
  include ActiveRecord::Store
  store_accessor :data, :last_backup_at
  def backup
    ...
  end
end
```

$ServiceBackupable::AWS

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_attribute' for ServiceBackupable::AWS:Module
    from /home/project/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/store.rb:69:in `block in <module:Store>'
```

How can i have create a module that has a store accessor?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I suppose that the module `ServiceBackupable::AWS` is meant to be used as a mixin (i.e. being included by other classes/modules). If that's the case, then you can make the module an `ActiveRecord::Concern`.

```
module ServiceBackupable::AWS
  extend ActiveSuport::Concern
  include ActiveRecord::Store

  included do
    store_accessor :data, :last_backup_at
  end
end
```

Note that the evaluation of the method `store_accessor` is deferred until the definition of the **class** which includes this module (directly or indirectly), not on this module itself.